# What is a "sound loan"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, etymology

I am going through Outlier dictionary for character 求:

> 求 depicts a centipede or millipede, indicating the original meaning “myriapod (a type of insect with a lot of legs).” It was borrowed for its sound (via sound loan) to represent the meaning “to seek, request.”

I do not understand what "sound loan" means. How is “to seek, request” the "sound loan" of 求 ?

Does it mean *qiú* was already in use for “to seek, request” without any character attached to pronunciation *qiú*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the *Outlier* entry there is a link to a gloss explaining the term:

> **Sound Loan** is when a character gets borrowed to represent a word for its sound, rather than its form.
>
> Ex. The form 我 wǒ which today means "I; me" was originally a picture of a type of weapon that consisted of a handle and a blade with saw-like teeth. The name of the weapon sounded similar to the word for "I; me," so it was borrowed to represent that word. Eventually, the meaning "I; me" took over completely and the form 我 was no longer used to represent the name of the weapon.
>
> Ex. The form 其 that now represents the word qí "his/her/its" originally depicted a basket. That word meaning "basket" is now written 箕 jī.

In *Outlier* you will often see the ○ icon in the meaning trees to indicate a [phonetic loan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Rebus_(phonetic_loan)_characters). Which are generally defined as a:

> character that is "borrowed" to write another homophonous or near-homophonous morpheme

So, yes, your assumption was correct - “to seek, request” originally existed as qiú without a specific character associated with it. The character「求」was then later borrowed as the readings matched.

Comment: for e.g 其 - was used to represent basket in Oracle bone/Seal script earlier , but never meant to mean his, her? in oracle bones or seal scripts no character for his, her ? at all?

Comment: Can you provide references to this statement: [ “to seek, request” originally existed as qiú without a specific character associated with it. The character「求」was then later borrowed as the readings matched.]

Comment: @r13 黃德寬，2007《古文字譜系疏證》，北京：商務印書館, p. 482 - the above information - including the question - is all based on the information found in *Outlier*, the reference is the reference that they provide.

Answer (score 4):

求 didn't mean "beg/request" initially. The meaning of beg/request was borrowed due to it having same sound. Phonetic loan characters 假借字 are one of the 六書. 求 is a classic example of 假借字. Another example is 北 (two people sitting back to back), which originally meant back. 北 had its meaning borrowed for "north" and the character with "back" definition is now 背

This is the first time I've heard of 求 as a centipede. The classic interpretation I know for 求 has always been a sort of combination comprising 毛 and 衣 meaning fur coat, where the character that means fur coat is now written as 裘. I'm guessing the centipede meaning is now written as 蛷. Both 裘 and 蛷 are fairly obscure characters, and are almost never really seen in modern usage.

https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E6%B1%82

Comment: thanks. but before 求 , chinese did not use request/beg in any of their scripts?

Comment: well, there is another character 乞 that also means beg, itself a phonetic loan from 气, but i am less familiar with reading the very old scripts though